# Check it 2 objects have the same property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 2 objects:

```
1. tempArr = { bookRetail: 14.99, hierarchyDescription: "GUYS DENIM PANTS [ 0151 ]", isSelected: true, isAvailableInPivot: "Y", style: "VICE NWH NAVY WHITE DC [ M450MBON ]"}

2. itemArr = { bookRetail: 14.99, hierarchyDescription: "GUYS DENIM PANTS [ 0151 ]", isSelected: false, isAvailableInPivot: "Y", style: "VICE NWH NAVY WHITE DC [ M450MBON ]"}
```

I want to compare these 2 objects irrespective of **isSelected** property value and if both objects are the same (except isSelected element value) i want to update **itemArr's isSelected** as true.

```
if (JSON.stringify(tempArr) === JSON.stringify(itemArr)) {
  itemArr.isSelected = true;
}
```

Currently the above code compare both array **including isSelected** element, how to exclude it while comparing.

Comment: Aren't you concerned with the fact that none of these is *array*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing two **`Object`'s** with `JSON.stringify()` doesn't seem to be a good idea as the order of keys in both parameters is not guaranteed.

Instead, I would suggest to loop through the `Object.keys()` with `Array.prototype.every()` and perform the check:

```js
const tempArr = { bookRetail: 14.99, hierarchyDescription: "GUYS DENIM PANTS [ 0151 ]", isSelected: true,isAvailableInPivot: "Y", style: "VICE NWH NAVY WHITE DC [ M450MBON ]"},
      itemArr = { bookRetail: 14.99, hierarchyDescription: "GUYS DENIM PANTS [ 0151 ]", isSelected: false, isAvailableInPivot: "Y", style: "VICE NWH NAVY WHITE DC [ M450MBON ]"}
      
      itemArr.isSelected = Object
          .keys(tempArr)
          .every(key => 
            key == 'isSelected' || 
            tempArr[key] == itemArr[key])
            
console.log(itemArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If comparing JSON strings are working for you as @Yevgen Gorbunkov pointed out correctly, then you could use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and get rid of the `isSelected` that way:

```
const withoutSelected = ({ isSelected, ...other }) => JSON.stringify(other);

if (withoutSelected(tempArr) === withoutSelected(itemArr)) {
  itemArr.isSelected = true;
}
```